# Change QuickBooks (or Outlook) HTML display settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When one of my users generates an invoice through QuickBooks and selects to have it sent via email it automatically populates the email with her form message.

[image]

You will notice that it defaults to be all on the left side. She would like this to be bigger taking up, ideally, 100% of the width of the email. This is not a setting available in QuickBooks that I can find, nor do I see something like this in Outlook.

Does anyone know how I can change this? Maybe finding the actual HTML or CSS file they use as a template? I can edit the code just fine if I can find that file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on SuperUser

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the Template?